# How to better formatting my HTML Table with titles and labels

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

How would I modify my code (below) to turn the table element (circled in red), into a table with a Title, and then headers above each column ("Load" and "kWh") for the left and right columns, respectively?

The elements, "name" and "watts" are what I want to create a label for ("Load" and "kWh"), in addition to a title above the table which says "Power Usage".  Right now, there is no formatting, and I am having trouble going from the tutorials at W3 schools, into my code.

```
function(){
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        if(!this.loaded) {
                wrapper.innerHTML = "Loading...";
                return wrapper;
        }
        if(this.xml !== null){
         var table = document.createElement("table");
         table.classList.add("xsmall", "table");
         var channels = this.xml.getElementsByTagName("channel");

         for(var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++){
           var row = document.createElement("tr");
           for(var n = 0; n < channels[i].children.length; n++){
                if(channels[i].children[n].tagName === "name" || channels[i].children[n].tagName === "watts"){
                var element = document.createElement("td");
                element.classList.add(channels[i].children[n].tagName);
                if (channels[i].children[n].textContent != 0){
            element.innerHTML = channels[i].children[n].textContent;
            row.appendChild(element);
            table.appendChild(row);
            }      
        else {
            table.removeChild(row); }
        }


           }
         }
         wrapper.appendChild(table);
        } else {
                console.log("Returned no Data");
                wrapper.innerHTML = "NO DATA";
        }
        return wrapper;
   },
```

First Try:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to build out a table similar to the following using the JS you've already written:

```
<table>
  <caption>Put title here</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Load</th>
      <th>kWh</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Kitchen Lights</td>
      <td>2.799</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note you can omit `thead` and `tbody` if you wish but be sure to use `th` instead of `td` for the first row to specify it is a header.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am having trouble recreating this in my JS.  Do I need 2 header variables? `var header` and `var header2`?  I am not sure how to separate the Load from the kWh.  I'll add a photo to my original post that illustrates this.

Comment: Right before your loop, just create a tr element called say headerRow. Then create two th elements called say header1 and header2. Append them to headerRow and append headerRow to the table before you start adding data in your loop.